# GeoServer could not get resources from Redis pool

Tags: redis, geoserver, jedis, geomesa

I want to store data with [GeoMesa](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation) into data store (e.g. Redis) and to visualize/publish this data with [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/).

I develop an interface (and the classes which implements this interface) in Java to store data in a Redis server. Then, the plugin "GeoServer with Redis" was installed.
Thus, when I add a new vector data source, GeoServer offers me the option "Redis (GeoMesa)". I get an error when I submit the parameters of this new data source in GeoServer. I try it before and after storing data in Redis, and the results are the same.
Redis was installed by the official Docker image.

Parameters to create a data

```
redis.url='localhost:6379'
redis.catalog='geomesa'
redis.connection.pool.size='16'
geomesa.query.threads='8'
geomesa.query.timeout=''
redis.pipeline.enabled=FALSE
redis.connection.pool.validate=TRUE
geomesa.stats.enable=TRUE
geomesa.query.audit=TRUE
geomesa.query.loose-bounding-box=FALSE
geomesa.query.caching=FALSE
geomesa.security.auths=''
geomesa.security.auths.force-empty=TRUE
```

GeoServer prints this output :
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Could not get a resource from the pool

Unfortunately, I don't access to the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your Redis instance is accessible on `localhost:6379`? Are you running Redis 5+ (GeoMesa was developed against Redis 5)?

You could try running through the Redis GeoMesa [quickstart](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-redis.html), which would eliminate any potential issues with GeoServer and should also show you a stack trace.

Comment: For the accessibility of Redis, I use two Docker instances, one for Redis (port 6379:6379) and one for GeoServer (8080:8080). This, I can access manually to these servers using my browser, but I don't know if they communicate between themselves.

Comment: For the version, '$ redis-server --version' prints : "Redis server v=5.0.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=7983a619928f1f2d". I am trying the Redis GeoMesa quickstart.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. However, both my geoserver and redis environment are dockerized and running in a VB Ubuntu virtual machine.

First, I port forwarded my redis port to my host IP. Then I pointed the geoserver redis URL to my host IP address instead of 127.0.0.1 or localhost.
This solved my problem.

If using your host IP address also works for anyone, kindly let us know.